# modelstate.isvalid always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, dropdownlistfor

i'm filling a dropdownlist as follow:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Department.Id, new SelectList(db.PhoenixIKDepartments.ToList(), "Id", "Name"))
```

I expect to have Id, Code and Name, but there is only Id and ModelState is false.

```
public class Phoenix_IK_Persons
{      
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Registry { get; set; }

    public Phoenix_IK_Departments Department { get; set; }
}

public class Phoenix_IK_Departments
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Lütfen Kod Giriniz!")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Lütfen Ad Giriniz!")]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

Can you please help me fill the dropdownlist properly with Id, Name and Code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Code` and `Name` aren't being populated on the model is because those fields aren't included ***and*** populated in the `<form>` tag anywhere. This line of code:

```
model => model.Department.Id
```

binds that drop down to that field. If you look at the HTML generated you will notice that the `name` and `id` attributes are indicative of that.

However, if you simply put in two hidden fields like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.Department.Code);
@Html.HiddenFieldFor(model => model.Department.Name);
```

they would get posted back with values. If you needed them to have a values you can simply assign them in JavaScript and when they are posted back they will be assigned to the model.